# Bulk inserting a dataframe using psycopg2 (error: 'dict' object does not support indexing)

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

Big thanks in advance, relatively new to psycopg2.

I'm trying to bulk insert data in the form of a pandas dataframe to my existing postgres database.

```
try:
    psycopg2.extras.execute_values(
                cur=cur,
                sql=sql.SQL("""
                INSERT into {table_name} ( {columns} )
                VALUES %s
                """).format(table_name=Identifier(entity),
                            columns=SQL(', ').join(map(Identifier, column_names))
                            ),
                argslist=dataframe,
                template=None,
                page_size=500)

except Exception as error:
    print(ERROR: ' + error)
```

I get the error below when I run this:

```
string index out of range
```

I tried changing the dataframe to a dict, using:

```
dataframe = dataframe.to_dict(orient='records')
```

The output that I am getting from the except clause is now as follows:

```
'dict' object does not support indexing
```

Any help hugely appreciated, I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8666415/5666087 answer your question?

Comment: In case you are passing dicts, your placeholder is `(%(dict_key_1)s, %(dict_key_2)s, ...)` instead of `%s`

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a case of an unhelpful error message. Quoting from another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8666415/5666087):

> You have to give `%%` to use it as `%` because `%` in python is use as string formatting so when you write single `%` its assume that you are going to replace some value with this.
>
> So when you want to place single `%` in string with query always place double `%`.

Try the following code, which replaces `%s` with `%%s`.

```
try:
    psycopg2.extras.execute_values(
                cur=cur,
                sql=sql.SQL("""
                INSERT into {table_name} ( {columns} )
                VALUES %%s
                """).format(table_name=Identifier(entity),
                            columns=SQL(', ').join(map(Identifier, column_names))
                            ),
                argslist=dataframe,
                template=None,
                page_size=500)

except Exception as error:
    print(ERROR: ' + error)
```

Comment: I get the error message: the query doesn't contain any '%s' placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use [pandas.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('"postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres"', echo=False)

df.to_sql('table_name', con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

Play around with this before you try this in production...

Comment: I've had a go at doing this and found it to be on the slow side, while reading about how to speed it up, I read elsewhere that to_sql is a less efficient way of doing this when dealing with larger volumes of data.and I should output to temp file and batch copy into the db. Not sure if you have any thoughts on this

Comment: i know there is a multi option in pandas to_sql. also if u r using sqlalchemy as ur connection, there is an insert many option that pscopg2 provides. somewhere in the docs. it will speed up ur insertions into the database table

Comment: You could try method 4 from this article: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/speed-up-bulk-inserts-to-sql-db-using-pandas-and-python-61707ae41990