# Postgres SQL query in Python sqlalchemy giving dict object does not support indexing

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a query like this where I am trying to fetch the distinct 'col1' records from table 'myTable' in the last 7 days .Doing a typecast based on the  timestamp format of 'date' column.

Here is the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1) col1 FROM myTable WHERE to_char(date, '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M') >= to_char(now() - interval '7day','%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M') ORDER BY col1,date DESC
```

Here is my code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@airflow-postgresql.temp-detector:5432/postgres"
engine = create_engine(conn)
query = "SELECT DISTINCT ON ({0}) {0} FROM {1} WHERE to_char(date, '{2}') >= to_char(now() - interval '{3}','{2}') ORDER BY {0},date DESC".format('col1', 'myTable','%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M', '7day')
recent_bad = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)
```

It fails after the read_sql line with this error **'dict' object does not support indexing**

Actually this is how my data looks in myTable

```
   col1        date
   2554386398  2023-03-25_07:41
   2554386398  2023-03-26_07:41
   2554386398  2023-03-26_14:06
   2554386398  2023-03-26_14:07
   2554386398  2023-03-26_14:19
```

Here is the complete error message

```
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/repo/automation/common/modules/mytest/mytest_utils.py", line 593, in read_historical_data
    recent_bad_fp_df = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 634, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1579, in read_query
    result = self.execute(*args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1424, in execute
    return self.connectable.execution_options().execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in execute
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 401, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3139, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1279, in execute
    future=False,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1585, in _exec_driver_sql
    distilled_parameters,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1846, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2030, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1803, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 719, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing
```

Can someone please help me as to what is going wrong here.

Comment: 1) Is `date` an actual `timestamp` type in the database? If so why all the  `to_char()` manipulation? A string format is for presentation not filtering, just use the `timestamp` type/field directly. 2) **DO NOT use format** for parameter substitution. [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html?highlight=read_sql) provides `params` as a way to do this, saves you from SQL injection.

Comment: Yes date is an actual timestamp which i am trying to convert to that specific date format in to_char()

Comment: 1) Why? The format has nothing to do with the filter expression `date  >= now() - ...` and it is an extra operation that also will nullify any indexes that involve `date`. In other words you are changing from a `timestamp` comparison to a `text` one with no benefit derived and actually making things most probably worst. 2) Add the complete error message as update to your question.

Comment: I have already referred to engine.execute(sqlalchemy.text(sql_query)) but it didnt work.Have shared my data in table as well here
as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657508/strange-sqlalchemy-error-message-typeerror-dict-object-does-not-support-inde

Comment: Have no idea what that has to do with your issue.  1) Per my previous comment add the complete error message as update to your question. 2) Read [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html).  3) Is `date`(bad name by the way as it not actually a date and it conflicts with the name for the type date) actually a `timestamp` type in the Postgres table or is it being stored as a string type e.g. `varchar`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Have updated the complete error message..The date is stored as varchar in database

Comment: 1) If that is the case then `to_char(date, '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M')` is not going to work as `to_char()` expects a `timestamp`, `timestamptz` or `interval` type as the first argument. 2) What does `print(query)` return when put just before `recent_bad = ...`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252802/discussion-between-pythonninja-and-adrian-klaver).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver can you please check the chat once.I have provided some more context and would request you to check once