# TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, dictionary, psycopg2, mysql-python, python-2.6

I'm working on this piece of code, python 2.6.6, old version because I will have to execute this script on linux servers(probably centOS 6, or Debian) with base repositories(stable) installed and no permission to install software that's not on these repos.

This snipped take care to select data from a database (mysql) with a certain schema(db structure), and insert it in an other database(postgresql) with a different schema.

```
cur_msql.execute("SELECT customerName, contactName, address, city, postal_code, country FROM tablename")

args_str = ','.join(cur_psql.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x) for x in cur_msql)

try:
  cur_psql.execute("INSERT INTO tablename (name, contact, address, city, cap, country) \
                    VALUES " + args_str)
except psycopg2.Error as e:
  print "Cannot execute that query", e.pgerror
  sys.exit("Leaving early the script")
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing
```

the following posts did not fixed my issue:

- [Psycopg2 using wildcard causes TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944276/psycopg2-using-wildcard-causes-typeerror)
- http://markmail.org/message/m2mmbqgq2emfqwex

In the [official website of psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#problems-with-type-conversions) I've found this, but I'm having bad times on understanding what it means:

> **Psycopg always require positional arguments to be passed as a sequence, even when the query takes a single parameter.** And remember
>   that to make a single item tuple in Python you need a comma! See
>   Passing parameters to SQL queries.

I do think my problem is related [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345825/typeerror-int-object-does-not-support-indexing#18345864) :

---

Comment: are cur_msql and cur_psql referencing the same db or different dbs? if they are accessible to each other you can just issue an INSERT .. SELECT query https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: They are referencing different databases, the source database is mysql, the destination database in postgres. It is a script to migrate data from one database to an other. The schema(db structure) on the two databases is different. Thankyou for your reply : )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cur_psql.mogrify needs positional parameters when you use it like that, but you can use [named parameters](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters) like `(%(customerName)s,%(contactName)s,%(address)s,%(city)s,%(postal_code)s,%(country)s)`

With that said, instead of having python make a huge string of parameters, consider instead using [cur_psql.executemany](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany):

```
cur_psql.executemany("INSERT INTO tablename (name, contact, address, city, cap, country) VALUES (%(customerName)s,%(contactName)s,%(address)s,%(city)s,%(postal_code)s,%(country)s)", cur_msql)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm analyzing it. I already had took in consideration the executemany method, but the I've discarded it, because it is over killing the performance, because this method, execute a lot of insert separately, instead the approach I'm trying will execute one insert of all the records. [Here they talk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query/10147451#10147451) of 100x more speed. And my script will have to deal with sizable datasets

Comment: Thanks, your first hint fixed my issue : )