# Pyscopg2 SQL Injection security with LIKE clause

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have to make a query which contains an SQL `LIKE` clause with the wildcard '%'. It also has user input data.

The query is of the form:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE x = <user_input>
AND y NOT LIKE '%abc%'
```

How do I do this in Python's `psycopg2` module?

The following code does not work:

```
cur.execute(
    """SELECT * FROM my_table
    WHERE x = %s
    AND y NOT LIKE '%abc%'
    """, (user_input,)
)
```

Probably because of the wildcards in the `LIKE` clause.

Any advice on how I should do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Psycopg2 using wildcard causes TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944276/psycopg2-using-wildcard-causes-typeerror)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass the pattern by a variable, e.g.:

```
pattern = '%abc%'

cursor.execute(
    """SELECT * FROM my_table
    WHERE x = %s
    AND y NOT LIKE %s
    """, (user_input, pattern)
)
```

Alternatively, escape the `%` characters in the pattern by doubling them (so the function does not treat them as placeholders):

```
cursor.execute(
    """SELECT * FROM my_table
    WHERE x = %s
    AND y NOT LIKE '%%abc%%'
    """, (user_input,)
)
```